# manage.py runserver - ImportError: No module named MYSITE

Tags: django, importerror, mysite, manage.py

I can't get the dev environment running!

I've been following the instructions [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server) (tutorial on DjangoProject page). When I type

```
manage.py runserver
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named MYSITE
```

I am executing the command within the folder MYSITE which has the files init.py, manage.py, settings.py, urls.py

I've searched around and found questions on "manage.py runserver", but not this specific error. Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using windows, you'll need to put your project's directory (the one with `manage.py` in it) into an environment variable called `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: No prob, if that doesn't work, do some Googling; it's very common for this to happen and there are a few things that can go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is highly ranked on Google and I got here while searching for an answer I'll share my solution:

I have a project built on my machine, packaged into a debian package and installed on a test machine. On my machine I use the runserver but on the testmachine I use apache (which was using fine). When changing database from sqlite to postgresql I could not do shell or syncdb etc (all manage commands). The problem here was that manage.py was owned by www-data and it had to be root for these commands to work...

```
sudo chown root. manage.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Another different answer ;) I'm walking the "Django for the Impatient: Building a Blog" chapter from "Python Web Development with Django" and it suggests creating a "dotted" module so I registered my application as "x.y" which it didn't like.  Changing to "y" which matched the file-system as:

```
/x
 + manage.py
 + /x
   + settings.py
 + /y
   + models.py
```

Worked for me.